# how to add xml node into an element

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

below is my current xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest identifier="_6czyDkzacOI_course_id" version="1.0" =>

  <organizations default="Education_Loan_ORG">
    <organization identifier="Education_Loan_ORG">
      <title>Title</title>
      <item "some attrib">
        <title>ACCOUNT PLANNING TOOL</title>
      </item>
    </organization>
  </organizations>
  <resources>
    <resource identifier="__6czyDkzacOI_course_id_RES" type="webcontent" href="index.html" >
      <file href="story_content/thumbnail.jpg" />
      <file href="mobile/linen_background.jpg" />
      <file href="mobile/player.css" />
      <file href="mobile/spinner.png" />
      <file href="story_content/fonts.xml" />
      <file href="mobile/data.gz" />
      <file href="mobile/data.js" />
      <file href="mobile/masks.js" />
      <file href="story_content/blank.html" />
      <file href="launcher.html" />
      <file href="story_content/orange_launch_normal.gif" />
      <file href="story_content/story.js" />
      <file href="ioslaunch.html" />
      <file href="mobile/mobileinstall.html" />
      <file href="index.html" />
      <file href="util/NONEFunctions.js" />
      <file href="util/UtilityFunctions.js" />
    </resource>
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

now I want to add another file tag like below

```
<file href="myJS.js" />
```

into **resource** tag

and this should be done using android only

below is the android code I am using

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;

            documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/26/imsmanifest.xml");
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);

            Element root= document.getElementById("resource");
            Element name = document.createElement("file");
            name.setAttribute("href","myJS.js");

            root.appendChild(name);
```

Please help me to achieve this

Comment: in which case you are using this file ?

Comment: i have a package which contains some html ,js, css and other files . adding the js file into manifest file is must because the js file is saved in mobile side

Comment: you can add that file into your assets folder

Comment: i already have js in my asset folder but to use with this package i need to copy it into the package folder and give the path reference in manifest file also.

Comment: please see my android code also

Comment: you really don't need that

Comment: just go through the assets folder

Comment: get file like this **file:///android_asset/26/imsmanifest.xml**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128451/discussion-between-mithilesh-izardar-and-rahul-khurana).